# Why does one light blink after installing new three way switches in my hall?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I installed the new switches with the wires in the same location the new switch this is a lighted one.  the hall way light blinks on one of the bulbs in the off position. Do i have a bad switch or will this switch just not work.  I installed new switches in the front room and all work ok.

Comment: Did you use the same type of switch, why did you replace the last one? What type of bulbs are you using? Is the bulb periodically flickering or a single blink and it stops?

Comment: Does the new switch use a neutral wire (white)?

Answer (score 2):

Likely you have CFL bulbs and no white wire ground.  If this is not your problem, it's somebody's problem who might read this.

The small leakage current through the lighted switch is enough to drive the CFL crazy.  Replace the CFL with a dimmable model, that might help.  Another brand might help.  Or maybe herbs and chanted words and some form of ceremony will make the flicker go away, hard to say.

Or find a lighted switch with a neutral connection that sends no current through your bulbs.
Or get some nice glow in the dark paint and put the regular switch back.